# Problem uploading file in Codeigniter if $config['base_url'] IS NOT EMPTY and $config['index_page'] IS EMPTY

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I followed the how to upload a file in codeigniter example shown in https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html and it worked just fine.

```
// Default values in config.php      
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

However I can't make if worked after I edited config.php based on my needs.

```
 // My desired values in config.php
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sample';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

My .htaccess looks like this (I don't actually know what these means):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I check with `empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`, it comes up empty with error saying

> You did not select a file to upload.

upload_form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $error;?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index() {
                $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }

        public function do_upload() {
                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 100;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                } else {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
        }
}
?>
```

How should I call the file to be uploaded with my preferred values in config.php?

Comment: Also add your .htaccess to the post and your upload code.

Comment: I've just added the codes in .htaccess. As for the other codes, I actually didn't change anything other than those two lines in config.php.

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

**Replace this code:**

```
// My desired values in config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sample';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**with this :**

```
// My desired values in config.php
$http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 
's' : '') . '://';
$newurl = str_replace("index.php", "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $newurl;
$config['index_page'] = '';
```